# Interesting sql split with two chars

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to write  function for split string with two chars.
Ex:**"Hyderabad Hyd,Test"**

In the above string i need to spit with space(" ") and comma(,) and the out result will keep in a table

```
The oputput should be:
Hyderabad
Hyd,Test
Hyd
Test


CREATE function dbo.SplitString   
    (  
        @str nvarchar(4000),   
        @separator char(1)  
    )  
    returns table  

    AS      
    return (  
        with tokens(p, a, b) AS (  
               select   
                1,   
                1,   
                charindex(@separator, @str)  
            union all  
            select  
                p + 1,   
                b + 1,   
                charindex(@separator, @str, b + 1)  
            from tokens  
            where b > 0  
        )  

        select  
            p-1 SNO,  
            substring(  
                @str,   
                a,   
                case when b > 0 then b-a ELSE 4000 end)   
            AS word  
        from tokens  
      )
```

Plz do help.....

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What type of database is this for?

Comment: You wouldn't also want `Hyderabad Hyd`?

Comment: Also what on earth are you using this for?

Comment: If you provide Hyderabad Hyd its awesome,This is for need to search with each word from user entered word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the results you showed, you don't need a *new* split function.  Just a normal one that takes a list and a separator.

```
SELECT
  second_split.*
FROM
  dbo.fn_split(@myList, ' ')   AS first_split
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT first_split.item
  UNION
  SELECT item FROM dbo.fn_split(first_split.item, ',')
)
  AS second_split
```

The first_split will be `Hyderabad` and `Hyd,Test`.

The second split will be...
- `Hyderabad` UNION `Hyderabad` which is just `Hyderabad`
- Plus `Hyd,Test` UNION `Hyd` and `Test`

Giving...

- `Hyderabad`
- `Hyd,Test`
- `Hyd`
- `Test`

Comment: hyderbad|
hyderbad hyd|
Test|
hyd,Test|   
hyderbad hyd|
Test|In my result i didnot get split with(,)

Comment: @Sree - Then you need to check your split function.  The code I gave gives the results you put in your question, and I explained as an example in the answer.

Comment: Sorry its my mistake.Its getting as i expected thank you so much..:)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. You might want to explore creating a SQL CLR  as it may be faster and easier to do the splits you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498(v=vs.100).aspx

Here's a blog post that may help as well.

http://dataeducation.com/faster-more-scalable-sqlclr-string-splitting/